# Problems with detecting collisions in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I'm creating a mobile game in unity 3D where you have to jump from one wall to another dodging spikes. I've got in fact two problems, both with collisions.  (btw. the game looks like its vertical, but in fact the camera is just rotated :) This is my player controller:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rgb;

    public float jumpStrenght;
    public bool walled;
    public bool jump;

    void Start()
    {

    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            Jump();
        }

        if(jump)
        {
            Jump();
        }

        if (walled)
        {
            rgb.isKinematic = true;
        }
    }

    public void Jump()
    {
        if (walled)
        {
            walled = false;
            rgb.isKinematic = false;
            rgb.AddForce(transform.up * jumpStrenght, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.CompareTag("Wall"))
        {
            walled = true;
        }
        //print("col enter");
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.CompareTag("WallEnd"))
        {
            walled = false;
        }
        //print("trigger enter");
    }

    void OnCollisionExit(Collision col)
    {
        //print("col exit");
    }


    public void OnPress()
    {
        jump = true;   
    }

    public void OnRelese()
    {
        jump = false;
    }
}
```

(sorry for messy code :)

1. OnCollisionExit wouldn't trigger when falling on the ledge
   (https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUbpI.png)
   I'm setting the rigidbody to kinematic to handle the situation when player is sticking to the celling
2. The collision with spikes won't trigger if the player isn't falling on them from up.
   [(The game is still playing)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljZde.png)
   This is the code for spikes:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Danger : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)
    {
        print("col");
        if(col.gameObject.GetComponent<PlayerController>())
        {
            print("colPl");
            GameManager.instance.EndGame();
        }
    }
}
```

If anything is unclear I'll be looking there every day to check for responses and I'll do my best to explain it beter. I'd be really happy to get this bug fixed because I was working on it for almost a week.

The OnCollisionExit method gets called even when player enters collision and isn't called at all when exiting collision. OnCollisionEnter isn't called when already colliding with ground.

Comment: Did you put all the tags like `Wall` , `WallEnd` to the correct GameObjects that have colliders ?

Comment: Yes. The OnCollisionExit doesn't register even when i put a debug.log - it just doesn't call

Comment: Try one thing, use `col.gameObject.CompareTag()` check in every collision calls. I am assuming as there is no tag checks in some places any object can get entered and exited without knowing which one. Lastly can you show how the colliders look in the scene view ?

Comment: Don't know how to add image in the comment :) They are not triggers and I made sure they are on the same GameObject as the tag.

Comment: It looks like your `walled` boolean is might be getting false. Look for your walled boolean in the inspector when it is getting false / true. It might be getting false due to being triggered by **OnTriggerEnter** for `WallEnd` tagged collider object

Comment: It doesnt even detet collisions with WallEnd. It was a solution for OnCollisionExit not working. However the Walled bool for some reason triggers also when OnCollisionEnter is active. When I send the message through console it looks like this: enter enter enter enter exit exit exit exit

Comment: That should be expected as your `walled` bool is inside `OnCollisionEnter` it will become true when `OnCollisionEnter` called.. what is the issue here then ?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding OnCollisionExit is not being called, it could be due to the player's Rigidbody being set to kinematic when in contact with the wall.

So here is what I think it should help. Instead of setting the Rigidbody to kinematic, try setting the Rigidbody's velocity to zero. Remove the lines that rgb.isKinematic = true;

Try the below and see if it solve your issue.

```
    void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
    {
        Jump();
    }

    if (jump)
    {
        Jump();
    }

    if (walled)
    {
        rgb.useGravity = false;
        rgb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
    }
    else
    {
        rgb.useGravity = true;
    }
}

public void Jump()
{
    if (walled)
    {
        walled = false;
        rgb.AddForce(transform.up * jumpStrenght, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }
}
```

Comment: doestn't work. Player just slowly floats from the right wall and doesn't stop.

Comment: Create physics material with zero friction to prevent the player from sliding down the wall when touching it then use the updated code I made and see if it works